# Failing to List.PushBack

Tags: list, go

Take a look at the following source code:

```
import "container/list"

type Stream struct {
    list list.List
}

func (s Stream) Append(value interface{}) {
    log.Println(s.list.Len())
    s.list.PushBack(value)
    log.Println(s.list.Len())
}
```

This code will keep on printing `0` and `1` all the time. Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're copying your Stream and List values in the Append method.

Either make `Append` a pointer receiver

```
func (s *Stream) Append(value interface{}) {
```

or make `Stream.list` a `*list.List`

```
type Stream struct {
    list *list.List
}
```

Comment: It works! Pretty strange, cos I checked addresses of list and they were equal... Thanks, anyway!